# Print from Hosted site to a barcode printer for ASP.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, barcode-printing

I have a website hosted using windows hosting which is written in ASP.net MVC. The issue I am facing is the code below

```
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
  pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Argox CP-3140L PPLB";
  pd.Print();

   void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Font printFont = new Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 17);
        Font printFont1 = new Font("", 16,FontStyle.Regular,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Font printFont2 = new Font("Officina", 10, FontStyle.Regular,GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Font printFont3 = new Font("Gill Sans", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(Session["QRcode"].ToString(), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(2);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(525, 350);
        Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5);
        Point point = new Point(130, 10);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1);
        g.DrawString(Session["Product"].ToString(), printFont1, br, 15, 5);
        g.DrawImage(bitMap, point);
        g.DrawString(Session["Brand"].ToString(), printFont2, br, 15, 25);
        g.DrawString(Session["SizeLead"].ToString(), printFont2, br, 15, 40);
        g.DrawString(Session["Rack"].ToString(), printFont3, br, 15, 55);
        g.DrawString(Session["BoxID"].ToString(), printFont2, br, 15, 70);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap1, 0,0);
    }
```

This is work fine when doing in localhost but when the code is running in hosted site the issue it creates is "Settings to access printer 'Argox CP-3140L PPLB' are not valid."

Any Solution how I can make this work on hosted site on Go Daddy.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you installed the driver for the printer "Argox CP-3140L PPLB" in your hosted environment? https://www.seagullscientific.com/downloads/printer-drivers/argox-cp-3140l-pplb/

Comment: I have hosted the site on shared hosting plans by go daddy can I install driver there. If yes then can you guide me ?

I have the drivers but not the way how I can install the drivers. I use plesk in hosting

Comment: I´m not familiar with Plesk hosting, but a quick google search led me to the following page where there are instructions by the looks of it to install drivers. Please try it out and let me know how it goes. https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/plesk-components/adding-and-removing-plesk-components.74719/

Comment: I had a chat with my hosting provider & they said that option is not avaliable for my plan. Is there any other way to print from a asp.net mvc project. I just want to print pdf. I can satisfy my goals by that